# Lambertian shader still not working

Tags: java, shader, raytracing

yesterday i posted this:

[Lambertian Shader not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29563842/lambertian-shader-not-working?noredirect=1#comment47285157_29563842)

My shader is still not working, I've done some debugging to try to find the reason. When I run my program and hit a sphere, shader.shade(renderable.colour) is called and this code is run:

```
public Colour shade(Intersection intersection, Light light){
    Vector3D lightDirection =  light.location.subtract(intersection.point);
    lightDirection.normalise();
    Normal normal = intersection.normal;
    normal.normalise();

    Colour finalColour = new Colour();
    float lambCoef = (float) normal.dot(lightDirection);

    if(lambCoef>0){
        finalColour.r = Math.max(0.0f, diffuseColour.r * lambCoef * light.intensity.r);
        finalColour.g = Math.max(0.0f, diffuseColour.g * lambCoef * light.intensity.g);
        finalColour.b = Math.max(0.0f, diffuseColour.b * lambCoef * light.intensity.b);


    }
    return finalColour;

}
```

I'm getting different values for lambCoef each time but not by very much for example for the red sphere, for pixels about 20 pixels vertical from each other, I get:
0.9446402
0.94463843
0.9446326
0.94462925
For to get the normal for the sphere I use:

```
public Normal getNormalAt(Vector3D point) {

    Normal normal = new Normal(point);
    normal = normal.subtract(center);
    normal = normal.multiply(-1);
    normal.normalise();
    return normal;

}
```

which seems to work.
Then for my dot and cross code I use:

```
public double dot(Vector3D vector){
    return x*vector.x + y*vector.y +z*vector.z;
}

public double dot(Point3D point){
    return x*point.x + y*point.y +z*point.z;
}

public double dot(Normal normal){
    return x*normal.x + y*normal.y +z*normal.z;
}

public Vector3D cross(Vector3D vector) {

    Vector3D crossedVector =  new Vector3D();

    crossedVector.x = y*vector.z - z*vector.y;
    crossedVector.y = z*vector.x - x*vector.z;
    crossedVector.z = x*vector.y - y*vector.x;

    return crossedVector;

}
```

Which also seems to be correct.
Any help would really be appreciated, and I'll be happy to provide more info if needed.

I'm now getting this sort of image:

[image]

Which sort of makes sense since the plane is at a much shallower angle to the spheres. It's still wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for using discrete `Normal`, `Point`, and `Vector` classes. In your `shade()` method, it doesn't look to me like you're accounting for the distance of the light source to the intersection point. Basically, you want intersection points that are further away from a given light to receive less light than points that are closer to the light. You can fudge this for point light sources by adjusting the light's `intensity` by a factor of `c / (distance * distance)`, where `c` is an empirically-determined lightness correction factor (start with 1 and then adjust upward if the result is too dark) and `distance` is the distance between the point light source and your intersection point. When I say adjust I mean add that term to the `finalColour` calculation, not actually change the value of `light.intensity`.

Once you get that working, you may want to think about sampling light sources in terms of PDFs instead of using the `1/d*d` hack.